# Declarative way to determine what group a user belongs to

Tags: formula, case, assignment-rules

Without using apex is there a way to find out what group(s) a user belongs to. Looking to build a declarative case assignment rule based on certain groups a user belongs to. Maybe using a formula field or FLOW to write to the Case record to us in the Assignment declarative code?

Comment: You can use flow, But again you have to query on the GroupMember Object to know the group names to which all user belongs to.

Comment: This is complicated because a Group can contain Groups that can contain Groups ... AND, a Group's membership can include role or roles-and-subordinates.

Comment: Thanks @cropredy and @H R

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe using a formula field or FLOW

- Formula field -- this won't work for the reasons below
- Flow -- this is complicated because of the relationship of users to groups

If you look at the schema for [User, Sharing and Permissions objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_users.htm) you will note:

- A Group can explicitly contain users via `GroupMember`
- A Group can include other groups that in turn contain other groups any one of which might identify a user via `GroupMember`
- A Group might reference a UserRole with (or without subordinates). A given user (might) possess that role or be a subordinate of that role.

Thus, determining if a given user is a member of a particular group is complex and while theoretically doable in Flow will be hard to test in a robust manner.

I would escape to an invocable Apex class to return a list of Group memberships that Flow can leverage. The Apex class can be thoroughly tested with testmethods to cover all use cases.